# KVM (Virt-Manager) GUI Not Opening

Tags: kvm, virt-manager

I cannot open KVM (Virt-manager) in GUI.

```
$ sudo virt-manager
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(virt-manager:24046): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:04:37.551: cannot open display:
```

Comment: Can you try without `sudo` and give us the output ?  
Is the `libvirt` service running ?